# Select all a-elements that enclose img-elements

Tags: jquery, css, image, css-selectors

I am searching. I am searching. Preferably, I would like an CSS-Selector, if not possible, jquery selector would also be nice.

Comment: "I am searching. I am searching." You've said that twice, but have you found anything?

Comment: rules, how to ask conventional conformist questions i found

Answer (score 5):

As it currently is, there are no parent selectors in CSS - yet anyways.

You can use the [**`:has` selector in jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/has/).

```
$('a:has(img)').css("background","red");
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/WU2wy/)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
var anchorThatContainsImage = $('a:has(img)');
```

Or:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var anchorThatContainsImage = $(this).parent('a');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS selectors this is currently impossible. It may be possible in Selectors Level 4 with the putative [subject identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), but that is still some way in the future.

It is possible with a jQuery selector, however. It's the `:has` selector:

```
$('a:has(img)')
```

or, more optimally, the `has` method:

```
$('a').has('img')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a img').parent ();

$('a').filter (function () {
    return $(this).find ('img').length > 0;
});
```